# How do I pull DotNetOpenAuth assembly references into unit test project for ASP.NET MVC4 solution?

Tags: dll, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, dotnetopenauth, .net-assembly

**Tl;dr version:**  I am stuck with the exception: *System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version 4.**0**.0.0 ...*

A bit dismayed that msft used so many static classes and methods for auth in the new MVC4 project template.  Want to wrap all membership/auth functionality into a class that implements an interface so that I can mock for unit tests.

After a couple of evenings of struggling, I have decided to start from scratch, so I removed all DotNetOpenAuth* assembly references and nuget package.config references.  I have similarly removed all references to Micrsoft.Aspnet.WebPages.OAuth.dll.

**Reinstalling packages:**  I run *install-package dotnetopenauth.aspnet* against three projects in solution which need the dll references.

Solution will not build, as my wrapper has a method which wraps: Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth(.dll).OAuthWebSecurity.RegisteredClientData and therefore I need a reference to this assy, so I run *install-package microsoft.aspnet.webpages.oauth* against the same three projects.

Solution builds, but when I run the unit test referencing  Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth(.dll).OAuthWebSecurity.RegisteredClientData I get a runtime exception:  *System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version 4.**0**.0.0 ...*

The references to this assembly in all three projects reference 4.**1**.0.0, as does the DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet assemblyIdentity in my web.config.

I'm using resharper to run the test, and the tests are nunit style.

And finally here is a paste of what I see in fuslogvw.  Obviously something is looking for 4.**0**.0.0 but I can't figure out what or what to do about it (I have a couple of times deleted the temp data folder referenced in this dump):

******* *Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/13/2012 @ 10:04:54 PM)* ********************

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.0\Bin\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.MSIL.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = i7\dave
LOG: DisplayName = DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/SVN/trunk/SoAndSo45/SoAndSo.Com.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Temp\kpsvgxtp.io4
LOG: AppName = SoAndSo.Com.Tests.Unit

## Calling assembly : SoAndSo.Com.Tests.Unit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/SVN/trunk/SoAndSo45/SoAndSo.Com.Tests.Unit/bin/Debug/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\SVN\trunk\SoAndSo45\SoAndSo.Com.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be able to install these as NuGet packages into your unit test project and have them work if you include these binding redirects to your test project's app.config file:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

If you have a fresh MVC project and run NuGet's `Update-Package` command on it, these are automatically created. If you hadn't run that, and installed the NuGet packages fresh into your unit test project, then your unit test project would have references to newer assemblies than your web project did. That would cause the load failure you saw, I think. You just have to make sure that either all your assemblies have common versions across your solution, or that the required binding redirects are in place. And in fact I think the binding redirects are required anyway, since the DotNetOpenAuth assemblies have been updated more recently than the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth` package has.

Comment: In hindsight it feels like I should have realized this would work because the .config settings were the only difference between my web project (which was working) and my unit test project (which was not), but honestly this never crossed my mind. You're good!

Answer (score 0):

Got some good help from a PM on the ASP.NET team at Msft, who recommended that I copy/reuse the collection of DLLs that are included in the MVC4 project template, which I have done and it's currently working for me.

I copied the DLLs directly to a "non-managed" folder outside of NuGet's purview so that they don't inadvertently get  updated unless I really want them to be.

Also worth noting, I had to clean out some references and assy forwarding in web.config to 4.1.0.0, since the MVC4 project template includes 4.0.* of all of the DotNetOpenAuth stuff.