# asp.net MVC 4 deploy on azure Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core'

Tags: deployment, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

Hello I am trying to deploy asp.net MVC 4 project on azure 
but I get this problem. I searched a lot about the solution but it looks like none 
suit my case, this is the Error message I get :

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Before the `dotnetopenAuth` have no reference in my project I downloaded 
but still get the same error .

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942653/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dotnetopenauth-core  useful?

Comment: NO its different problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374277/how-do-i-pull-dotnetopenauth-assembly-references-into-unit-test-project-for-asp

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I came across a similar problem and this question popped up as the closest case. This was my issue:

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2013/09/26/windows-azure-websites-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dotnetopenauth-core.aspx

Being, a previous MVC project had been deployed, which contained these references. I deleted them by downloading the publish profile, and, with the "Remove additional files at destination" option checked, I published to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

While publishing, you can select "Remove additional files at destination" and then publish again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with continuous deploy between visual studio online and azure.

I modified my build file and changed the "Do Not Delete" setting under "Deployment" in the "Process" Tab to False.

Good to go.

Answer (score -1):

This is a case of version mismatch. The error itself says that `manifest definition does not match`.

Look carefully at the version of the referenced assembly and the version shown in error message.

In case you are not using openauth you can remove it's reference all together.