# Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core'

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to implement OAuth in my existing MVC4 website. I had everything working in a test site, and everything was working fine on this particular site. I'm presently getting this error [image], but my web.config looks like this: [image]. I tried [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374277/how-do-i-pull-dotnetopenauth-assembly-references-into-unit-test-project-for-asp), I've tried GACing the components, I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the NuGet packages, I've tried clearing out the ASP.NET temp files, I honestly don't know what else to try... except maybe put my fist through my monitor.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, I solved the problem. It was because the project was upgraded from MVC 3, and I had the MVC 4 assembly in the  list. Once I rebuilt the web.config from a new MVC4 project , the bindings stopped getting their wires crossed and the app started working again.

If you run into the same problem and want more details, reply here and I'll post them.